# Encountering 'denied: Not Authorized' error while pushing Docker image to AWS ECR Public registry

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecr

I followed the steps provided by AWS documentation to push a Docker image to an AWS ECR Public registry. However, during the final step of pushing the image, I encountered a "denied: Not Authorized" error.

Here's what I did:

Retrieved an authentication token and authenticated my Docker client to the registry using the following AWS CLI command:

`aws ecr-public get-login-password --region <your-region> | sudo docker login --username AWS --password-stdin <registry-url>`

Built my Docker image using the command:

`sudo docker build -t my-app .`

Tagged the image:

`sudo docker tag my-app:latest <registry-url>/my-app:latest`

Attempted to push the image to the AWS repository:

`sudo docker push <registry-url>/my-app:latest`

However, during the last step, I encountered a "denied: Not Authorized" error. I have ensured that I have the latest versions of both the AWS CLI and Docker installed.

Could someone please help me identify why I'm receiving this error and provide guidance on how to resolve it? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!